# Determine the convergence value...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\text{a)} \ \ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{5^{k+1}+(-3)^k}{7^{k+2}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{b)} \ \ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log\bigg(\frac{k(k+2)}{(k+1)^2}\bigg)$$

I am trying to determine the convergence values. I tried with partial sums and got stuck...so I am thinking the comparison test...Help

Comment: First: try to break it into the difference of two (geometric) series. For the second: use properties of the logarithm to split the summand in 3 or 4, hoping to make a telescopic series appear?

Answer (score 3):

HINTS:

$$\frac{5^{k+1}+(-3)^{k}}{7^{k+2}}=\frac5{49}\left(\frac57\right)^k+\frac1{49}\left(-\frac{3}{7}\right)^k$$

$$\log\left(\frac{k(k+2)}{(k+1)^2}\right)=(\log (k)-\log (k+1))+(\log (k+2)-\log (k+1))$$

Then, telescope the two series.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, use  summation [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) of Infinite geometric series

For the second, $$\log\dfrac{k(k+2)}{(k+1)^2}=\log\dfrac k{k+1}-\log\dfrac{k+1}{k+2}=u(k)-u(k+1)$$

where $u(m)=\log\dfrac m{m+1}$

See [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: nevermind, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{5^{k+1}+(-3)^k}{7^{k+2}}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{5^{k+1}+(-3)^k}{7^{k+2}}=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{182+\left(-\frac{1}{7}\right)^{m}3^{1+m}-5^{3+m}7^{-m}}{490}=$$
$$\frac{1}{490}\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(182+\left(-\frac{1}{7}\right)^{m}3^{1+m}-5^{3+m}7^{-m}\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{490}\left(182+0-0\right)=\frac{182}{490}=\frac{13}{35}$$